# probably another closure-loop issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

I am importing a set of notes into my webpage, this is to read a JSON file locally in a loop and append the read data into the main div. No problem till now. But then I'm producing a ckeditor instance beside each note for the client to become able to easily add comments to his note of interest. The comments are initially generated as several indexed empty div's in another HTML file, loaded into the ckeditor instances. However, all these happen in a really large for loop (I have almost 6000 notes to be loaded in a segmented manner using if conditions), and so now I'm engaged with the classic closure-loop problem. Have read several previous questions and answers foo this and other websites and tested a number of them to get rid of the closure-loop problem, but no success so far.

The related segment of my java script has the structure:

```
var q;
$.when(
    $.ajax( ... loads the json file that contains the notes and set q=$.parseJSON(data) on success)
).then(function() {
    for(var i in q) {
         if(i is in a specific range){
                ... several lines of code for properly importing the notes ...
                ... and generating a place for the comments to appear as:
                ... +'<div id="CKEditor'+i+'" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Put your comment here!"></div>'
                ... which is appended to the main div of the webpage
                ... Now the main problematic part begins:   

                $('#temporary').empty();    // a hidden div defined somewhere in the page       
                var func = (function() {
                     var ilocal=i, tmp;
                     return function() {
                         tmp=document.getElementById('temporary').innerHTML;
                         alert(tmp);
                         CKEDITOR.instances['CKEditor'+ilocal].setData(tmp);
                     }
                })();
                $.when(
                    $('#temporary').load("NewComments.htm #verse-"+i)
                ).then(func);
         };
    };
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inlineAll();
})
```

maybe the problem is not for the loop but for the nested $.when().then(), any suggestion to resolve the issue?

Comment: I guess your actual problem is that every iteration uses the very same `$('#temporary')` div. The closure itself looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is only a single `$('#temporary')` div in your page, which will be re-used and overwritten by every iteration. In particular, in your callback

```
document.getElementById('temporary').innerHTML;
…
CKEDITOR.instances['CKEditor'+ilocal]
```

the `ilocal` (and `tmp`) variables are indeed local to the IIFE and that particular iteration, but `document.getElementById` is global. It will return the same element every time.

A quick fix is to create a new element for every request, and assign it to `tmp` during the iteration (like you assign `i` to `ilocal`) instead of when the `func` is called.
A much better practice however would be not to use `$('#temporary').load("NewComments.htm #verse-"+i)` multiple times, and instead load the `NewComments.htm` only once per Ajax and process the result as you need.

Comment: thanks a lot for mentioing that `document.getElementById` is global, and also for your kind suggestions